# Should I be getting a warning box from the android browser in a cached html5 app when offline?

Tags: android, html5-appcache, android-2.3-gingerbread

Using Android 2.3.5 Gingerbread built in browser.  Created an offline cached app using html5.

When I turn the network off, the pages seem to cache ok but moving from page to page I get a message warning me there is No Network Connection (with settings / OK buttons).  If I press OK you can move to the next page (also cached) but my users are not happy having to press the OK button every time they go from one cached page to the next.

On a an Android 4.0.4 tablet, the internal browser does not generate the message when network is off.

Can anyone confirm that this is standard Gingerbread behavior for a cached HTML5 app or did I do something wrong?  Is there any low level setting to suppress that message?

My only other thought is to cram all the pages into a single page and show/hide them rather than navigate from page to page.  Or just build a native app.

I'd switch to Chrome but it won't run on Gingerbread.